# Decryption of cipher text encrypted using AES(128) encryption with ECB mode

Tags: apex, encryption

I am aware that SFDC supports decryption using AES(128 bit) using CBC mode. But I have a requirement  where I need to decrypt a cipher text encrypted using AES(128 bit) ECB mode.

One way of doing this is using Javascript. But this approach presents issues on security front.

Is there some other way to accomplish the same?