# Compare Encryption: Apex Differs From Java?

Tags: apex, encryption

I am converting Java code to apex. Purpose of the code is to encrypt . But apex is not giving the same result as java. Could someone help me to fix the code.

**Java Code:**

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

class EncryptionUtil {
    public static String encrypt(String input, String key) {
      byte[] crypted = null;
      try{
        SecretKeySpec skey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
          Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
          cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skey);
          crypted = cipher.doFinal(input.getBytes());
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
        return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(crypted));
    }

    public static String decrypt(String input, String key) {
        byte[] output = null;
        try{
          SecretKeySpec skey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
          Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
          cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skey);
          output = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(input));
        }catch(Exception e){
          System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
        return new String(output);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      String data = "sampleuser";
      String key = "secrettoencrypt1";
      System.out.println(EncryptionUtil.decrypt(EncryptionUtil.encrypt(data, key), key));
      System.out.println(EncryptionUtil.encrypt(data, key));        
    }   
}
```

**Apex Code:**

```
Blob PrivateKey = Crypto.generateAesKey(128);
System.debug(PrivateKey.size());
System.assertEquals(16, PrivateKey.size());

Blob data = Blob.valueOf('sampleuser');
Blob encryptedData = Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV('AES128',blob.valueOf('secrettoencrypt1'),data);
Blob decryptedData = Crypto.decryptWithManagedIV('AES128',blob.valueOf('secrettoencrypt1'),encryptedData);
String EncryptedDataString = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(encryptedData);
String decryptedDataString = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(decryptedData);

system.debug('This is encrypted data   '+ EncryptedDataString);
system.debug('This is decrypted Data   '+ decryptedDataString);
```

Comment: Are you planning to run this as anonymous Apex? I don't even see where you've declared this as a class.

Comment: I am starting this as an trigger. Except trigger name everything else i posted here.

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to turn your results into a base64 string - it's pretty hard to get a readable string after you do that.

Instead, just call the `Blob.toString()` method:

```
system.debug('This is encrypted data   '+ encryptedData.toString());
system.debug('This is decrypted Data   '+ decryptedData.toString());
```

Running this in the console appears to generate the value that you want.

---

**EDIT - A possible workaround for the not valid UTF-8 String error**

```
Blob PrivateKey = Crypto.generateAesKey(128);

Blob data = Blob.valueOf('sampleuser2423423---234234%%@#!!!ˆˆˆøø¥');
Blob encryptedData = Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV('AES128',PrivateKey,data);
Blob decryptedData = Crypto.decryptWithManagedIV('AES128',PrivateKey,encryptedData);

String decryptedHexString = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(decryptedData);
Blob decryptedBlobString = EncodingUtil.convertFromHex(decryptedHexString);

system.debug('This is decrypted Data   '+ decryptedBlobString.toString());
```

---

**EDIT 2** 
Given that you are actually just trying to match the two encryption systems, you should probably investigate this method, which allows you to specify in initialisation vector (defined [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm#apex_System_Crypto_encrypt)):

```
encrypt(algorithmName, privateKey, initializationVector, clearText)
```

In Java, you can specify the Vector as shown (from [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2288/sample-java-class-to-decrypt-aes128-encryption)):

```
byte[] iv = ...; /* your IV */;
IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);
```

Once you have the two vectors the same, I think you should be closer to your goal.

Comment: BLOB is not a valid UTF-8 string is the error i am getting if i do as you suggested.        system.debug('This is encrypted data   '+ encryptedData.toString());

Comment: I've see a technique used where you convert to a hex string as in intermediary step - I'm unable to break it btw. I've put the full code in so you can see.

Comment: I realised you also have a bug in your Crypt implementation - I fixed it when testing the first time, but forgot to tell you :) - answer updated.

Comment: But used secretkey for encrypt/decrypt. I am not seeing them in your code conversion. secrettoencrypt1 is my secret key...

Comment: I see you have used "secretkeytoencrypt" as a placeholder for your actual key - I'm assuming it's the right length? Are you still getting UTF-8 errors? (have edited my answer again)

Comment: I am not getting error, but output i seeing out of apex and java code is completely  different.. java code gives me 46 char string after encryption, whereas Apex gives me output of 96 char. my main goal is to match the output of java.

Comment: Oh. You probably should have said that in your question.

Comment: how to proceed now? would you be able to help me

Comment: I think the issue is the initialization vector - normally salesforce handles this for you in the method you are using. Look here encrypt(algorithmName, privateKey, initializationVector, clearText)

Comment: if you can specify the vector the same in both Java and Apex, you should have a better chance of matching them.

Comment: I even tried it, it is not matching the java output. But char lengths coming closer.

Comment: That's about all I can contribute, unfortunately.

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/56694/decryption-of-cipher-text-encrypted-using-aes128-encryption-with-ecb-mode?rq=1 someone also had similar problem and no one answered that as well. thanks a ton for trying to resolve my issue.

Comment: Are you able to modify the Java? you probably have more control there...

Comment: 3rd party application does the decryption part. we already have a java system that talks to it. Java system uses the above code, i am trying to re-create the code in apex, so i will also be able to integrate with the same 3rd party application. changing java code will not be useful to me.